# VirtualBox for Android development

Tags: android, virtualbox

I have installed Android 4.3 with VirtualBox and I want to use this machine to test some applications of mine. The main reason to not use qemu is that it doesn't run with vboxdrv service started; actually, I can't stop the service cause I have a lot of VMs opened.

How can I do this? 
I read on the web that I have to know the Android machine IP address. Is that true? How can I do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: linux os or windows?

Comment: use Genymotion emulator

Comment: @Pr38y I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

Comment: @ZiedRebhi it downloads a bin file. What am I supposed to do with this?

Comment: Genymtion emuylator runs on VirtualVox ,  it's fast to test app android https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/doc/ , this a tuto by me (Fr) http://www.tutozone.info/2014/07/genymotion-emulateur-rapide-en-android.html

Comment: @ZiedRebhi it gives me some problems. When I execute `./genymotion
`, it writes to a log file in the home. It says
`ott 10 11:25:54 [Genymotion] [Fatal] Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40806) with this library (version 0x40802)
`

Comment: you should have one version of Qt library

Comment: @ZiedRebhi yes, I found something similar on the web but I'm still not able to solve the problem. I'm opening a new question on AskUbuntu; can I post the link here?

Comment: @ZiedRebhi problem solved using this solution
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2207219&p=13048000#post13048000

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) emulator it runs on VirtualBox.